# Чем заменить метод $emit (который раньше был в socket.io)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Необходимо просто сгенерировать событие из другого модуля, для дальнейшей обработки.

пример 
otherModule.js

```
 exports.post = function (req, res, next) {
  var sid = req.session.id;
  var io = req.app.get('io'); 

  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    io.sockets.$emit('session:reload', sid);
    // ...
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};
```

Обработчик в socket.js

```
io.sockets.on('session:reload', function(sid) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: а кто отменил `emit()`, я не пойму!?

Comment: с просто emit() он туда не попадает.

Comment: с просто emit() и не надо, чтобы попадал. делай по мануалу http://socket.io/

Comment: @mix можете тыкнуть носом в строчку , либо я слеп , либо глуп ну я не понимаю о чём вы

Comment: `tw.on('tweet', function(tweet){ io.emit('tweet', tweet); });` - пример получения, обработки и ответа с помощью socket.io с официального сайта. @Mr_Epic примерно показал то, как должен отправляться ответ.

Comment: да и я бы с вами согласился , переписал код как указанно.
получение
`io.on("session:reload",function(sid){
 console.log("123456");});`

отправка 

`io.sockets.emit("session:reload",sid);`

не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так

в socket.js

```
io.on("sessreload",function(sid){
//some code
});
```

в otherModule.js

```
exports.post = function(req, res,next){
  var sid = req.session.id;
  var io = req.app.get("io");
  req.session.destroy(function(err){
    io.sockets._events.sessreload(sid);
    if(err) next(err);
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

Comment: понятия не имею кто выбрал это ответом...
вот я получаю:
TypeError: io.sockets._events.session_reload is not a function

Comment: @c00p3r.web по всей видимости они опять переписали что то , теперь только в документации искать этот метод , но ответ всё же верный 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543758/how-to-call-socket-io-custom-server-event

Comment: @izac как же нерабочий код может быть верным ответом?
Если он работает только в определенной версии - то думаю стоит это указать. В **socket.io 2.0** решение **не работает**

Comment: @c00p3r.web да нужно поправить, работает для версии  socket.io 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Просто `emit`, в чём проблема та?

```
io.sockets.emit('session:reload', sid);
```

Comment: с просто эмит не выходит тк он отправит всем сокетам .

мне же нужно сделать событие на самом socket io 

метод с $ должен сделать серверное событие  как обычный eventemitter.